# Error installing Rails on Ubuntu 11.10 (Gem::DependencyError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 11.10, but receiving this error:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 3.2.3), actionpack (= 3.2.3), activerecord (= 3.2.3), activeresource (= 3.2.3), actionmailer (= 3.2.3), railties (= 3.2.3)
```

How can I fix this?

Note: Git (1.7.5.4 ) and Ruby (1.9.2p290) are installed properly.

Comment: Have you tried my solution below? It seems you have posted this question on a lot of forums and groups, but this is your answer. What has happened, if you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do the install without the sudo? does that work? If so, it may be a gem path / permissions issue. If that works, or even if it doesn't, check out ['sudo gem install' or 'gem install' and gem locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations)

Answer (score 0):

It is [suggested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-talk/AoUYZCKEJbY/Iop-fFyjH1kJ) to use the [RVM](https://github.com/YogiZoli/RVMinstallerForUbuntu)

Also, according to [rails 3.2.0 and heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953338/rails-3-2-0-and-heroku) it seems you need to play with versions and typically not use the packaged version from your distribution but some GIT or other repo.

Comment: On 11.10, because of dependency issues, yes. This will also be of some help: http://www.railway.at/2010/02/13/avoiding-rails-3-dependency-hell-with-rvm/ and if you have trouble setting up the RVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626701/ruby-gems-under-rvm-on-ubuntu-failing-to-install-in-the-wrong-location